# Does Orisa's Halt! displace a Bastion in Sentry configuration?

Tags: overwatch

The new hero Orisa has the "Halt!" ability, which lets her pull together enemies in a small radius. Bastion in Sentry configuration is immune to Lucio's Soundwave and Pharah's Concussive Blast, but can be moved by Zarya's Graviton Surge.

Since Orisa's Halt! is similar to Graviton Surge in both lore and execution, can it move a Bastion in Sentry configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it moves Bastion, but like Zarya's ult, it does not change him out of sentry mode.

Comment: It's a bug. I added a another answer as per [this meta thread suggested](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5679/should-i-add-a-new-answer-if-a-previous-one-is-partially-correct)

Comment: I'll update my answer if/when it actually changes.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in PTR it does but it's not meant to and it has been logged as a bug

https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753187460

> The pull effect from Halt! can unintentionally drag immune heroes, like Bastion in Siege mode, or Mei while she is inside Cryo-Freeze.

I'm assuming Siege mode means Sentry mode and is a misspell on the part of Blizzard.

Comment: Do you know if this was fixed in the current version of Overwatch?

Comment: Haven't played extensively in the last month and I haven't done an actual test but I think I have seen Mei's Cyro-Freeze being immune. So I'm guessing it has been fixed but I wouldn't take what I just said as reliable evidence.